# What happen with modifications queries when JDBC application abnormaly exited or connection dropped (Oracle is this essential)?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I call extensive **update** SQL statement and **PL/SQL** procedures.

What will happen with data when my application lose connection to DB or server halted or etc?

In case of SQL **update** command I think that it will be rollback.

For PL/SQL procedure I assume that code execution stopped at some time, any previous  **commit** command will be applied but rest of code doesn't.

Am I  right?

Comment: Make sure you set `autocommit` to false on the Connection object rather than default true. Don't have commit statements in the stored procedures. Then you need to explicitly issue a commit from your java program after all work is done to complete the transaction. Any interruption will result in rollback.

Comment: I use 2 **commit** statement in PL/SQL as code work faster (one after **truncate table** and another after a zillion of **insert**). Just practical measure without any reasoning based on official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should rollback to the last rollback/commit call.

Answer (score 0):

This became too long for a comment.

DDL statements (truncate, create, drop,...) implicitly commit. So if you do that in your stored procedure calls, everything before that statement will be committed whether you want or not. If the jdbc session is lost after the truncate, the changes before are still committed.

And yes, if you are inserting large volumes without intermediate commits, things can slow down. This is typically because you are building up rollback segments. There is a sweet spot with large inserts where you insert a batch of, say, 1,000 records at a time, committing after each batch.

What you are describing does not seem like normal transactional activity but more like bulk loading. If you are bulk loading, then maintain state so that you can restart the load or discard the records already loaded if you replay. Consider things like shipping as a file and importing (or using an external table) rather than necessarily inserting via a client connection. The `APPEND` hint and INSERT's `NOLOGGING` clause to speed up inserts (but note that the db will not be in a typical 'recoverable' state afterward and should be backed up again).